# Scala integration with Mongodb

Tags: scala, mongodb

We're using mongodb, and rewriting parts of our stack with scala. I'm wondering if I should stick with mophia, or use a scala mongodb library such as subset.

Question is what do I get out of subset? e.g. with mophia I don't have to manually define the mongodb field names like i have to do in subset...

Is subset really worth using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do have to define models in Morphia, in order to use it to map to objects. Don't have time for a proper answer, but here's a quick comment: I've not used subset--only salat, and for some things only casbah. The scala-style syntax alone is superior than trying to force Morphia into scala, in my opinion.

Comment: yeah in both the model you have to define, but subset requires you to define the mapping of individual fields, where morphia introspects the model class.

Comment: sounds like salat is superior to subset, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

We use [casbah](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah) + [salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) and it works well in almost all cases.

Comment: There is no stable salat version for 2.10 at this moment, by you can try 1.9.2-SNAPSHOT. We use it in production and it works well too.

Answer (score 0):

With Scala you should consider using [Casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/), which is an officially supported interface for MongoDB that builds on the Java driver.

> Casbah's approach is intended to add fluid, Scala-friendly syntax on top of MongoDB and handle conversions of common types. If you try to save a Scala List or Seq to MongoDB, we automatically convert it to a type the Java driver can serialize. If you read a Java type, we convert it to a comparable Scala type before it hits your code. All of this is intended to let you focus on writing the best possible Scala code using Scala idioms. A great deal of effort is put into providing you the functional and implicit conversion tools you’ve come to expect from Scala, with the power and flexibility of MongoDB.
>
> Casbah provides improved interfaces to GridFS, Map/Reduce and the core Mongo APIs. It also provides a fluid query syntax which emulates an internal DSL and allows you to write code which looks like what you might write in the JS Shell. There is also support for easily adding new serialization/deserialization mechanisms for common data types.

Comment: The DSL for casbah is cool, and it's nicely idiomatic for scala. However, the goal of morphia is to do object mapping from mongo documents, where casbah is more like the java driver, just giving you access to a map that you can pull primitives (or nested maps) out of--nothing for object mapping built-in. That's why a lot of people use salat or subset on top of casbah (or even morphia or the jackson-mapper--the java-oriented mappers).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the ORM-Mapper/Client-Libraries, I would suggest you give [Rouge](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue) a try. It will serve you with a nice Query DSL for Mongo. Rogue 1.X will only support [Lift-MongoDB](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/MongoDB) but version 2.x (which will ship in very near future) will work for a lot more MongoDB libraries.

A sample query would be (pure Scala code with compiletime typechecking):

```
Venue where (_.mayor eqs 1234) and (_.categories contains "Thai") fetch(10)
```

which queries for 10 entries in the Venue collection where 1234 is the mayor and Thai is one of its categories.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of **Subset**. I would say "Subset" is not really a kind of ORM library. It has no methods for working with databases and collections, leaving it to Java/Scala drivers. But it is more focused on transformations of MongoDB documents. This transformation core is rather generic and suitable not only for reading/writing of fields, but for applications that need perform e.g. document migrations as well. Query/Update builders Subset provides are built on top of this "core".

That said, if you need ORM, there are simpler alternatives indeed. I never had an intent for Subset to compete with true ORM libraries, I've filled the gap I met in my projects.

Comment: Could you please provide example of mapping DBObject to case class ? I went through `Extractors` in your documentation but it shows mapping to individual fields only. Thanks!

Comment: This probably deserves a separate question?